# WebRTC Oovoo AuthenticationFailed

Tags: webrtc, conference, oovoo

I registered on oovoo developer, I entered 127.0.0.1 as the domain.

I have included the token (WEB TYPE) in:

```
appToken var = "**********";
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{"Meta": {"code": - 30000, "message": "AuthenticationFailed"}}
```

I also tried to enter the conferenceID manually, but the problem is not solved.

```
conferenceId var = "12345";
```

IsSandbox is true

Oovoo it still? twitter, github / oovoodev and everything else is old at least 1 year

Answer (score 0):

Oovoo WebRTC requires a domain to be entered in app setting tab, in your case you need to add your local IP or add localhost url if it is not added. For ref, I am adding an image of Application Settings:

[image: Application Settings]

Comment: i figured out when i pasted app token on sublime editor, it shown incomplete string while on NPP its showing full string. So it might be possible that due to editor full sting not pasted. I know its not a solution but please check it if you found nothing copy the log and raise ticket to oovoo

Comment: I Use sublimetext3, I took your advice and tried with atom, but the token is the same, unfortunately I could not solve.

I opened a ticket three days ago, I have not received a reply, and I think they did not even read

Comment: could you please send me your local url from which you are requesting oovoo.

Comment: I use linux, I tried it with sublime-text / atom / gedit and chrome / firefox, unable to solve, in addition to video-chat even normal chat works, the same error.

I use the token type WEB.

In the documentation he tells me to also change the appID

"Make sure you edit the .html files or your own code to include your AppID, APP Tokens & conference ID (RoomID)"

But in addition to the token in the code I do not see anything else to change. My local url? http://localhost/oovoo.html you cannot connect

Comment: if you are using localhost not 127.0.0.1 then add localhost as Domain in oovoo dashboard.It will defiantly work because I tried it today before posting comment